# Binding click to dynamically created div isn't wortking

Tags: jquery, bind

I've set up this to bind a click to the anchor within any dynamically created divs with the class "expFold"

```
$('body').ready(function()
{
    $('.expFold').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    alert('here');      
});
}
```

I hardcoded a div into the page to check that the click is working...

```
<div class="expFold"><a href="#">▼</a></div>
```

And it does.

However, any divs added later like so...

```
$("#myParentDiv").append('<div class="expFold"><a href="#">▼</a></div>');
```

...don't respond to the click.

Anything obvious jump out as to why they don't respond?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Only the current document has a ready handler

Answer (score 3):

You need event delegation. try this:

```
$('#myParentDiv').on('click', '.expFold a', function (event) {
  alert('here');
});
```

Comment: This is called event delegation, all infos [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)

Answer (score 1):

Since your `div` created dynamically to the DOM, the click event will not be available for these links. In this case, event delegation will help you to attach that event.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', ".expFold a", function (e) {

        alert('working');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First , put your code of binding in a function :

```
function bidingDivClick(){
   $('.expFold').on('click', '.expFold a', function (event) {
    alert('here');      
});
}
```

After that , call this function when appending the div into your html :

```
$("#myParentDiv").append('<div class="expFold"><a href="#">▼</a></div>');
bidingDivClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to delegate your event ...

```
$(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        var $t = $(e.target), doc = this;
        // Testing whether the element that triggered the event was what an anchor inside a ".exFold"
        if($t.is('.expFold a')){
            alert('Anchor clicked !');
        }

    });
});
```